# Tagging the directories and switching between them by tags

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, file-system, console, bash

**MOTIVATION**

I have this small software package that allow users to maintain a simple text file that looks like

```
tag1 path1
tag2 path2
.
.
.
```

For example, it may look like

```
home ~
root /
funk ~/funky/funk
```

Now, suppose the user is in the root directory `/`. When the user types `dt funk`, his current working directory changes to `~/funky/funk`. As an additional feature, the user may type in simply `dt` and his current directory will be changed to `/`. Typing `dt` again, will change the current directory back to `funk`. This way, it is convenient to work between two distinct directories.

Also, what comes to tag matching, my implementation allows approximate matching using Levenshtein distances in case a user makes a typo.

**OTHER SOFTWARE**

There is already similar programs that are more feature reach than this one, one of them is [bashmarks](https://github.com/huyng/bashmarks/blob/master/bashmarks.sh). There should be at least one similar program as well; I don't recall how it is called.

**CONSTRAINTS**

As a child process cannot change its parent's current working directory, there is no way you can achieve directory switching behaviour from a compiled program; you need to work with scripting facilities of **bash** as well.

**DESIGN**

Basically, you have

1. a text file `~/.dt_table` containing **tag**/**path** entries
2. the actual script `~/.dt/dt_script`
3. the program for converting a tag into a path `~/.dt/dt_engine`
4. an alias `alias dt="source ~/.dt/dt_script"`

What comes to the alias, regardless where you put it (`.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`), don't forget to rerun that very file so that **bash** knows what to do when it encounters a command `dt`.

**CODE**

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::min;
using std::numeric_limits;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

static const char* TABLE_FILE_NAME = ".dt_table";
static const char* PREVIOUS_TAG_FILE_NAME = ".dt_prev";

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements the algorithm for computing the Levenshtein distance between two  *
* input strings.                                                               *
*******************************************************************************/ 
static size_t get_edit_distance(string s1, string s2, int i, int j) 
{
    if (i == 0) 
    {
        return j;
    }
    else if (j == 0)
    {
        return i;
    }

    return min(min(get_edit_distance(s1, s2, i - 1, j) + 1,
                   get_edit_distance(s1, s2, i, j - 1) + 1),
               get_edit_distance(s1, s2, i - 1, j - 1) +
               (s1[i - 1] != s2[j - 1] ? 1 : 0));
}


/*******************************************************************************
* Computes the Levenshtein distance between two input strings.                 *
*******************************************************************************/ 
static size_t get_edit_distance(string s1, string s2) 
{
    return get_edit_distance(s1, s2, s1.length(), s2.length());
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the name of the current working directory.                           * 
*******************************************************************************/ 
static string get_current_directory() 
{
    return string(getcwd(NULL, 0));
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the name of the user's home directory.                               * 
*******************************************************************************/ 
static string get_home_directory_name() 
{
    return string(getenv("HOME"));
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Writes to the file called 'prev_file_name' the name of the current directory *
* denoted by 'current_directory'.                                              *   
*******************************************************************************/ 
static void save_current_directory(string current_directory, 
                                   string prev_file_name) 
{
    ofstream file_out;
    file_out.open(prev_file_name, ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc);
    file_out << current_directory;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Processes the input tag by looking in the table file for tag/path pairs. If  *
* the table is empty, the directory is not changed. If the table file is not   *
* empty, this function tries to find the tag whose Levenshtein distance is no  *
* more than 2, and if found, changes the current working directory to the path *
* of the closest tag.                                                          *        
*******************************************************************************/ 
static void process_tag(string input_tag) 
{
    string home_directory_name = get_home_directory_name();
    string table_file_name = home_directory_name + "/" + TABLE_FILE_NAME;

    ifstream f(table_file_name);

    string tag;
    string directory;

    size_t best_edit_distance_so_far = numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
    string best_directory;

    while (f >> tag >> directory) 
    {
        size_t edit_distance = get_edit_distance(tag, input_tag);

        if (best_edit_distance_so_far > edit_distance)
        {
            best_edit_distance_so_far = edit_distance;
            best_directory = directory;

            if (edit_distance == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (best_edit_distance_so_far > 2) 
    { 
        // Do not change the directory.
        string current_directory_name = get_current_directory();

        if (current_directory_name == "/") 
        {
            // Handle this special case so that the path is printed as 
            // "/" and not "//".
            cout << "/" << endl;
        } 
        else {
            cout << get_current_directory() << "/." << endl; 
        }

        // Just return so that the previous tag is not updated.
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Yes, we have (at least approximate) match. Change the directory.   
        if (best_directory[0] == '~') 
        {
            // Once here, the first character is '~' (tilde); substitute it 
            // with the actual home directory name.
            cout << home_directory_name 
                 << best_directory.substr(1, best_directory.length() -  1);
        } 
        else {
            cout << best_directory << endl;
        }
    }

    // Update the file holding the previous directory.
    string prev_file_name = get_home_directory_name() 
                            + "/" + PREVIOUS_TAG_FILE_NAME;

    save_current_directory(get_current_directory(), prev_file_name);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Changes the current working directory to the previous one.                   *
*******************************************************************************/  
static void move_to_previous_directory()
{
    string home_directory_name = get_home_directory_name();
    string prev_file_name = home_directory_name + "/" + PREVIOUS_TAG_FILE_NAME;

    ifstream file_in(prev_file_name);
    string previous_directory;
    string current_directory = get_current_directory();
    file_in >> previous_directory;

    // Move to the previous directory.
    cout << previous_directory << endl;

    // Write current working directory as a previous one.
    save_current_directory(current_directory, prev_file_name);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc >= 2) 
    {
        string tag = argv[1];
        process_tag(tag);
    }
    else 
    {
        move_to_previous_directory();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiling main.cpp**:

```
g++ main.cpp -o dt_engine
```

**dt_script**:

```
if [ "$#" -ge "1" ]; then
    cd $($HOME/.dt/dt_engine $1)
else
    cd $($HOME/.dt/dt_engine)
fi
```

**DEMO**

Now, your session may look like:

```
[~] dt rot
[/] dt
[~] dt
[/] dt forgt
[~/forget] dt
[/] dt
[~/forget] cd uni/
[~/forget/uni] dt
[/] dt
[~/forget/uni] dt home
[~] dt
[~/forget/uni]
```

So what do you think?

Comment: You should be aware that there is shell builtin called `pushd` which accomplishes what this seems to be aimed at.  The other related shell builtins include `popd` and `dirs`.  Check out `man bash-builtins` and search for each of these three in turn.

Comment: @Wildcard That's probably why OP attached [tag:reinventing-the-wheel].

Comment: @Mast Yes, and he made a mention of other *software* packages that do this.  But there is a difference between a software package and a shell builtin.  Either way, I thought I should mention what wheel, specifically, is being reinvented.

Comment: @Wildcard Fair enough. OP may want to use that information to clear-up the post. Better post = better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Previous path

Currently you store the previous path in a file.  This could be problematic if you have two shells open, because they will each overwrite the same file.  I would recommend storing the previous path in an environment variable so that each shell can have its own previous path.